# CSS animate one direction, flip then animate back

Tags: css, animation

I am trying to animate a sailboat to go horizontally from left to right, then flip the boat and animate it back from right to left, then loop.

I've got the right to left going fine. Not sure how to handle the flip and right to left part.

```
.sailBoatContainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    animation: move 20s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
    from {
        left: 0;
    }
    to {
        left: 100%;
    }
}

    <div id="sail" class="sailBoatContainer">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 98 103.18">
        <defs>  
            <style>.sail1,.sail5{fill:none;}.sail1{stroke:#e1e1e1;}.sail1,.sail5,.sail6{stroke-linecap:round;}.sail1,.sail6{stroke-linejoin:round;}.sail2,.sail6{fill:#d3dfdd;}.sail3{fill:#f4f4f4;}.sail4{fill:#f1263a;}.sail5{stroke:#ae8863;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:2px;}.sail6{stroke:#c2ccca;}.sail7{fill:#7f604c;}
            </style>
        </defs>
        <title>sailboat</title>
        <g id="rigging">
            <path id="roperight" class="sail1" d="M1.48,89s37-35.67,50-70.33" transform="translate(-0.48 0)"/>
            <path id="ropeleft" class="sail1" d="M51.48,20.33c16,37.34,46,62.67,46,62.67" transform="translate(-0.48 0)"/>
        </g>
        <g id="cabin">
            <path id="cabinbox" class="sail2" d="M51.48,82v8h27V87s-9-5-12-5ZM62,83.5h4v4H62Zm-6,1h3v3H56Z" transform="translate(-0.48 0)"/>
        </g>
        <g id="sails">
            <path id="sailright" class="sail3" d="M86.48,72s-23-43-33-49c0-1,11,24-4,46C49.48,69,75.48,68,86.48,72Z" transform="translate(-0.48 0)"/>
            <path id="sailleft" class="sail3" d="M48.48,14s-49,35-34,66c0,1,35,0,35,0S44.48,38,48.48,14Z" transform="translate(-0.48 0)"/>
        </g>
        <g id="flag">
            <path class="sail4" d="M52,1.5s-2,2-3,2-8-2-11,0c0,0,6,1,8,4h6Z" transform="translate(-0.48 0)"/>
        </g>
        <g id="mast">
            <line id="mastline" class="sail5" x1="51" y1="88" x2="51" y2="1"/>
        </g>
        <g id="hull">
            <path id="hullbox" class="sail6" d="M90,101.5s-78,4-89-4v-9s79,2,97-6C97,83.5,99,90.5,90,101.5Z" transform="translate(-0.48 0)"/>
        </g>
        <g id="hullbottom">
            <path id="hullbottombox" class="sail7" d="M91.87,99.88S21.5,104,.5,97v2s8.73,6.94,89.73,2.94Z" transform="translate(-0.48 0)"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Here is a [Codpen](https://codepen.io/west4me/pen/gXVpNg)

I'd appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Start by moving from two to three "steps", 0%/50%/100% instead of from/to. Move all the way to the right at 50%, and back to 0 at 100%. And then throw in some `transform` to "mirror" it from 50% on as well. FYI, `left: calc(100% - 250px);` helps to make it turn around when it reaches the right window edge, instead of going over by the ship's width and causing scrollbars ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Not sure how to handle the flip and right to left part.

Start by moving from two to three "steps", 0%/50%/100% instead of from/to. Move all the way to the right at 50%, and back to 0 at 100%.

(`left: calc(100% - 250px);` helps to make it turn around when it reaches the right window edge, instead of going over by the ship's width and causing scrollbars ;-)

And then throw in some `transform:scaleX` to "mirror" it from 50% on as well.

But that will actually require inserting a fourth step - otherwise scaleX will *slowly transform* from -1 to 1, and he boat will end up *"rotating"* ... so to keep it at -1 up until we get to 50%, throw in a frame a 49.999%:

```
@keyframes move
{
    0% {
        left: 0;
      transform: scaleX(1);
    }
    49.999% {
      transform: scaleX(1);
    }
    50% {
      left: calc(100% - 250px);
      transform: scaleX(-1);
    }
    100% {
      left: 0%;
      transform: scaleX(-1);
    }
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZagbXN

Comment: That's what I needed. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

you can use keyframes like this in animation

```
@keyframes move
{
  0%   {
    left: 0;
  }
    50%   {
    left: 100%;
  }
    100%   {
    left: 0%;
  }
}
```